# Sum coefficients

Tags: summation

Assume this equailty:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$
Does $$a_n = b_n$$ hold for every $a_n$ and $b_n$?

Comment: If $a+b=c+d$ must it be true that $a=c$ and $b=d$?

Answer (score 2):

$a_1=1, a_n=0$ for $n\geq 2$ and $b_1=b_2=\frac{1}{2}, b_n=0$ for $n\geq 3$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I proof if a_n = b_n without evaluating the sums?

Comment: @Daniel A counter-example suffices as a proof.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can't prove something which is false.

Comment: @Daniel to prove that a statement is false, a counterexample is enough. If it is false, as Mark says, there's nothing to prove, just show that there is at least one situation where it is false.

Comment: Of course, you're absolutely right. But in my comment I said IF.

Answer (score 2):

There are of course, more than enough counter-examples to the statement mentioned in the post. This should intuitively be clear too, because you have only one condition $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$ but infinitely many statements to prove $$a_n=b_n \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N} \tag{1}$$

However, $(1)$ would be true ;-) if you were given $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^k a_n = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^k b_n \ \forall k\in \mathbb{N}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let consider as counter example any convergent series such that $a_n=b_{n+1}$ with $b_1=0$ with $b_n>0$ strictly decreasing for $n>1$.

---

Therefore we can claim that for any convergent series $\sum a_n$

- $a_n=b_n \Rightarrow \sum a_n=\sum b_n$ (trivial)

but

- $\sum a_n=\sum b_n \not \Rightarrow a_n=b_n $

Note that the latter doesn't mean that the implication

- $\sum a_n=\sum b_n \Rightarrow a_n=b_n $

is always false but that some case exist for which it is false, as all the counter examples presented here have shown.